# Stackoverflow exception on Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

I am using Linq to SQL to access my SQL Ce database.

```
var Logcontext = new LogContext(GCUtility.LconnectionPool.Connection);
{           
 var _ApplicationsK = (from u in Logcontext.Applications select u.PK_Key).ToList<int>();
}
```

In the above code PK_Key is an auto-incremented integer variable in database. It throws an exception "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll". I tried cleaning, rebuilding, restarting etc on Visual Studio. I am using Linq runtime version v4.0.30319. Whats wrong in my code?

The table structure is like below.

```
PK_Key (Type = int, PrimaryKey = true, Identity = True, Identity increment = 1, seed =1 )

Username (Type = varchar, AllowNulls = True)
```

Linq SqlMetal.exe generated the following code for the coloumn PK_Key

```
 [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage = "_PK_Key", AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType = "Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int PK_Key
    {
        get
        {
            return this._PK_Key;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._PK_Key != value))
            {
                this.OnPK_KeyChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._PK_Key = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("PK_Key");
                this.OnPK_KeyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How many rows does the table have? Also, can you post the rest of the method containing the query? `_ApplicationsK` should be allocated on the heap so regardless of it's size it can't cause a SOException. More likely you're putting a very large structure on the stack by accident.

Comment: When you get a stack overflow exception, a good place to look for the problem is the stack trace.

Comment: Insertion works without any problem. So far I tested only below 30 rows.

Comment: @Jehonathan You're probably un-intentionally ending up recursing in your event handling, filling the stack with recursive calls.

Comment: I never recursed anywhere in my logic. I followed the execution path, and it throws the exception when it called ToList(). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027628/linq-to-sql-stackoverflow-exception-when-querying-objects have a related question which points to a Linq 3.5 bug. There they have said "When using 'Auto Generated Value' = True, then you must set 'Delay Loaded' to False - otherwise you get the recursion error." But I don't know how I can do that, where is 'Delay Loaded' need to be set? Also where to see the stack trace in visual studio?

Comment: Sorry guys. But your comments were useful to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the actual problem, I had another child class which inherited this class. The above code was in the constructor of parent class. I instantiated inherited child class within my parent class causing an infinite loop. Stupid me.